# How does UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE work?

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js cluster with one worker process created using cluster module and have fixed the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZ`E as 1. But when I am using:

```
ps -eLf | grep node
```

I am getting way more number of threads. Here is the snippet of ps command output:

```
root      3803  2027  3803  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js 
root      3803  2027  3804  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js 
root      3803  2027  3805  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js 
root      3803  2027  3806  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js 
root      3803  2027  3807  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js
root      3803  2027  3808  0    6 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3809  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3810  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3811  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3812  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3813  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js 
root      3809  3803  3814  0    7 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js
root      3809  3803  3833  0    7 14:59 pts/0    00:00:00 /root/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node /root/cluster.js
```

Here is the node.js code:

```
Const cluster = require('cluster'); 
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs'); 
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1;
const numCPUs = 1

if (cluster.isMaster) {<br>
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((request, response) => {
    if (request.url == "/page.html" || request.url == "/") {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./page.html").pipe(response);
  }
  else if (request.url == "/index.js") {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./page.html").pipe(response);
  }
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Comment: Did you find anything till now ??